# Opening multiple links in default browser as tabs, why do I get multiple windows?

Tags: python

I have just made a simple script that opens links from a hand typed list in the default browser. It succeeds at opening the pages, but often opens 2 or three windows with all the pages spread out across. What am I missing?

```
import webbrowser

new = 2

def open_page(url):
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

line_len = file_len('social.txt')

with open('social.txt') as f:
    content1 = f.readlines()

for i in range(line_len):
    url = content1[i].rstrip()
    open_page(url)
    print url
```

Comment: default browser is... ?

Comment: Firefox in this case. I just meant that I wasn't targeting a specific browser in the script so it just goes to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is up to your browser. As the documentation for [`webbrowser.open`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) says:

> If *new* is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible.

So, why might it not be possible?

At least two reasons, and probably more:

- When you call `webbrowser.open` the second time, it hasn't finished opening the first window yet. So, when it tries to create a new tab in the current window, there *is* no current window, so it creates a new tab. This may happen a few times if you're spamming it as fast as possible (as you are). Not every browser works this way on every platform, but some do. This is particularly likely in cases where the "browser" program is actually just a script that talks to the real browser program, as with the `firefox` script on most *nix platforms except Mac OS X.
- When you call `webbrowser.open` the 13th or so time, that exceeds some limit on max tabs/window, so it opens a new window. I believe Gecko-based browsers have this feature but it's disabled in Firefox (as in, you have to dig into `about:preferences` or edit `prefs.js` to set a limit), WebKit-based browsers don't have it at all, and I have no idea about IE or Opera.

Again, those are just two possible reasons.

---

So, how do you fix this? Well, it depends on the problem.

First, there are already some hacky workarounds to avoid the first problem with some browsers. In particular, if you're on a *nix platform, and your default browser is Firefox, but Python can't figure that out (and it's therefore just using `$BROWSER` and/or using `xdg-open` or similar), explicitly using `firefox` instead of the default may help.

But beyond that, this is a classic race condition. The solution to any race condition is to find the right thing to synchronize on. But there's no way to do that in this case. You're calling a function that kicks off a chain of events and gets no feedback whatsoever (e.g., it executes a wrapper script that talks to the real browser program that may itself just be a front-end that sends a message over a pipe to the real real browser program…). As the docs say:

> For non-Unix platforms, or when a remote browser is available on Unix, the controlling process will not wait for the user to finish with the browser, but allow the remote browser to maintain its own windows on the display.

As usual with races, you can sort of paper over them with `sleep`s, but it's never a good solution. No matter how long you sleep between the first and second call, it's not guaranteed to be always long enough—and it's almost certain to be usually too long.

If you dig through the source for [`BackgroundBrowser`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/webbrowser.py#l185) and the `UnixBrowser`, `MozillaBrowser`, etc. that follow it, you can see that there are some hacks that you might be able to extend that might work in some cases. Or, you can go deeper under the covers and talk to a specific web browser using some more powerful specific API that it provides via, say, COM or AppleEvents or over some pipe or on the command line. But short of that, there's no real answer. (Well, you might be able to use something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) that knows how to drive a number of different browsers, but it's the same basic idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Here how I searched multiple questions from a .txt file

```py
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd

ques = pd.read_csv('ques try.txt', sep='\n')  
for i in ques['questions']:      
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={i}')
```